# How do I add tags to Advanced Forum posts

Tags: nodes

I would like to add the type of tags this stackexchange forum has, so users can tag their posts and the tags appear at bottom of all posts. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

**1.** If you want to create the Tag in the new topic content, you can follow as suggested by the @lixu (This method will add the tag below the body content, but you can also shift its position up-down by going at `manage-field`). But this method will not show the tags on the advanced forum topic list.

> [image: Tags to the content of topic]

**2.** If you want to create the tag at the list of topics page, like stake-exchange but not completely like that, You need to go to views. Advanced forum provides 5 views, Go to `Structures->Views->Advanced Forum topic list->Edit`, to the field add new field `Content: tags`.

You can rearrange the position of it by rearranging option(Check second image). I have added to the last as shown in the image. What this will do, it will add one more column of Tags in the topic list page, besides the last-post column(check third image). You can shift the column of tag wherever you want, by shifting the tag filed in views.

> [image: Adding tags through views]
>
> [image: Display on the advanced forum list page]

Answer (score 0):

in drupal 7 admin mode, structure->content types->forum topics->click manage field,

add existing field, select field_tags/Autocomplete term widget (tagging)

tags now exist for forum post