# Tags won't show on Advanced Forum Module

Tags: views, nodes

I am using Drupal 7. I'm struggling to get the tags to show on my forums within the Advanced Forum module.

I have configured them within the `manage fields` settings

[image]

but they will not show anywhere else on my forum pages.
I have checked the Drupal listing [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130532/how-do-i-add-tags-to-advanced-forum-posts) and tested both suggestions, still no change (even after clearing cache.)

What am I doing wrong or missing?

FYI: Please before suggesting any other tag modules, please help me with my current setup and Advanced Forum module. Thank you.

---

Answer (score 0):

Dev error: They weren't showing on any of the posts, because it was a new field, hence once you make the new post and select tags for them, then post, then they show just fine.